# apt pin priority for a single package in a source

Tags: firefox, debian, apt

I am trying to get firefox through the debian repo for mint to work within debian wheezy
I'm using the following source line:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import
```

i've created a file in:

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/
```

called mint and it looks like the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=debian
Pin-Priority: 1
```

and I have a second file called firefox in the same directory, as follows:

```
Package: firefox
Pin: release a=debian
Pin-Priority: 900
```

and finally a third file, ./iceweasel,  to minimize iceweasel priority:

```
Package: iceweasel
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1
```

I realized that if I did nothing but add the mint repo then bash, for example, would think that it would need to be upgraded based on the results from the mint repo. My goal is not to low prioritize every individual package within the debian mint source. I want to low minimize them all with a single higher priority for firefox only. I'm new to the apt pin priority. Please advise with my syntax. Thanks in advance

see output below

```
apt-cache policy firefox

firefox:
  Installed: 34.0.5~linuxmint1+betsy
  Candidate: 34.0.5~linuxmint1+betsy
  Package pin: 34.0.5~linuxmint1+betsy
  Version table:
 *** 34.0.5~linuxmint1+betsy 900
          1 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian/import amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


apt-cache policy iceweasel
iceweasel:
  Installed: 31.3.0esr-1~deb7u1
  Candidate: 31.3.0esr-1~deb7u1
  Package pin: (not found)
  Version table:
 *** 31.3.0esr-1~deb7u1 1
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     24.4.0esr-1~deb7u2 1
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages

apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3
  Candidate: 4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3
  Version table:
     4.3-9.2 0
          1 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian/import amd64 Packages
 *** 4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7u3 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It would be wiser for you to get the latest Iceweasel instead from http://mozilla.debian.net/

Comment: @teresaeJunior thanks, but the point for me in this is to learn and understand apt pinning, not to actually get the specific package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file, let's call it */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01stable*, with the following content:

```
 APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

Now create a file called */etc/apt/preferences* with the following content:

```
 Package: firefox*
 Pin: release n=stable
 Pin-Priority: -10

 Package: firefox*
 Pin: release n=debian
 Pin-Priority: 900
```

Comment: Could you give another example for how to pin a package from Ubuntu 20.10 if you are still using 20.04?

Comment: I found the solution, it is explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) for Ubuntu hardy and intrepid, just replace hardy with focal (20.04) and intrepid with groovy (20.10)